# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift2

I am getting Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error (clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)) . 
I just moved my code from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0. I am using pods.
And now i am not able to build my Project. I am using Xcode 8.3.3.

Thanks in advance for Help.

Comment: Are you getting only this much "linker command failed with exit code 1"?

Comment: your project is missing some framework. Either native framework or third party framework of podfile.

Comment: yes @angshuknag

Comment: Delete your pod directory and pod lock in project then go to terminal select your project path, give pod install

Comment: Go to Xcode preferences -> Location-> Derived data. Remove the Derived Data folder. Perform a clean on your project. Re compile and do not modify any of your files while the linker is running

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for your comments.

There was an pod FAN library issue.
I just removed and install again to pod file.
issue solved.